# Remover palavras após caractere específico python

Tags: python, replace

Olá. Preciso encontrar uma maneira de padronizar as seguintes classes em python

```
db.groupby(["EdLevel"])["EdLevel"].count() 

Master's degree                                                                       11141

Master's degree (M.A., M.S., M.Eng., MBA, etc.)                                       13112

Master's degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)                                           19569

Master's degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)                                          21396
```

E o código precisaria resumir tudo a "**Master's degree**"

Eu sou novato em programação, e estou totalmente perdido. Eu pensei em utilizar um **replace**, porém existem dezenas de classes diferentes, mas todas seguem o mesmo padrão: "Nível educacional" + "(outras graduações)" Se eu conseguir retirar tudo que está após o "(" eu poderia diminuir meu código

Desde já agradeço a ajuda

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é usar regex:

```py
import re

degrees="Master's degree (M.A., M.S., M.Eng., MBA, etc.)"

print(re.findall(r'.+(?=\s\()', degrees))
```

Retorna:

```
["Master's degree"]
```

---

A expressão regular `(?=...)` é um *positive lookahead*. Esse tipo de expressão regular checa se determinado padrão ocorre e pega o que vem antes (nesse caso:`.+`), **excluindo** o padrão.

Para aplicar isso a um `DataFrame` você vai precisar definir uma função. Veja:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['degree']=["Master's degree","Master's degree (M.A., M.S., M.Eng., MBA, etc.)","Master's degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)","Master's degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)" ]

def get_degree(k):
    if '(' in k:
        return re.findall(r'.+(?=\s\()',k)[0]
    else:
        return k

print(df.degree.apply(get_degree))
```

Retorna:

```
0    Master's degree
1    Master's degree
2    Master's degree
3    Master's degree
Name: degree, dtype: object
```

Se todos os casos que você usa terminam em "degree", ficaria mais fácil, pois bastaria usar o *postive lookbehind*. Esse tipo de expressão regular checa se determinado padrão ocorre e pega o que vem antes (nesse caso: `.+`), **incluindo** o padrão:

```py
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4, 4), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
df['degree']=["Master's degree","Master's degree (M.A., M.S., M.Eng., MBA, etc.)","Master's degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)","Master's degree (MA, MS, M.Eng., MBA, etc.)" ]

print(df.degree.str.extract(r'(.+(?<=degree))'))
```

Retorna:

```
                 0
0  Master's degree
1  Master's degree
2  Master's degree
3  Master's degree
```